# How to install jq in Cloud Composer environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, installation, airflow, jq, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to install `jq` package in Cloud Composer environment but it is getting failed.

https://pypi.org/project/jq/

I understand that it requires some additional dependencies to get resolved. Is there any way to install those pieces (e.g. autoconf) in composer environment?

Comment: Which Python version do you use?

Comment: Composer is build with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Python libraries that implement bindings fail at runtime if the libraries don't exist on the system. `jq` fails at installation time (breaking the build) if the libraries are missing. This means it is incompatible with Cloud Composer, because getting shared libraries into the build environment is not currently supported.

You won't be able to install `jq` from `PyPI`, but you can still install it as a [local Python library](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-local). Note that this will require you to install the shared libraries yourself in your `/dags` folder, or your `/plugins` folder, please refer to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage). You will also need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to that directory (example: `/home/airflow/gcs/dags`), depending on which directory path you chose.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: I can confirm that it is still not possible to install jq on a cloud composer worker. I tried both apt-get and webinstall. Both failed.